# How to create a built-in delay in opening files with apps in Windows 10?

Tags: windows, cygwin, delayed-execution

I am running Windows 10, with Cygwin.  I also have 4NT installed and can use commands from that if it helps.

I usually open files for editing via the command line.

I would like, for one particular file, to implement an automatic delay before it open. So that if I type `vi FILENAME`, FILENAME will open not immediately but fifteen minutes later. (Yes, I realize this probably sounds crazy.)

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Yes, it's called a shell script.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, got it:

```
if "%1" = "xxx" delayopen %1

if "%1" != "xxx" \cygwin64\bin\vi.exe %1
```

where delayopen.bat is:

```
sleep 900

call c:\cygwin64\bin\vi.exe %1
```

What I wasn't aware of was the "sleep" command.

Comment: Since you are using this in a Cygwin environment, wouldn't it make sense to write it as a shell from Cygwin, i.e. bash, zsh, ksh, ..., instead using a Windows batch file? It will also be easier if you want to expand it later on, since the Batch language is pretty restricted, compared to bash and its friends.

Comment: @user1934428 :  If I did everything sensibly, I wouldn't have needed this script in the first place!   For the record, I have hundreds of batch files, written over decades, that freely mix dos, 4NT and cygwin commands, all of which I run from a 4NT command prompt.  I often use commands I'm familiar with, but where I've long since forgotten what language they're in.   I suspect, for example, that the "if" statements above are in 4NT syntax and would not run under DOS --- but I'm not actually sure.   These are probably very bad habits, but also very ingrained.